# Famo.us install gives me a a blank browser page with the famo.us icon

Tags: famo.us

I ran all the commands for installing the famo.us developer tools.  All went well until the last step of `grunt serve`.  It just popped up a Chrome window with a big famo.us logo in the middle but other than that it does nothing and I don't see any options/buttons I can click.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything. That is the example app that is generated during the scaffolding process.

Look for the file  app/src/main.js ..

This is your main javascript file. What you currently see in the browser is being generated from that file.

Was there something else you were expecting to see?

Comment: For some reason I was expecting it to be an interactive editor like the one in the famo.us lessons.  Now re-reading it I think my brain just read it wrong before.  Thanks!

Comment: No Problem! Have fun!